# ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings - flush to disk

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there a way of flushing `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` to disk? I cannot find any documentation about when the value is persisted after setting it.

The root problem is that is in some abrupt shutdown scenarios (e.g. power off, system restart) my colleagues claim that we intermittently experience lost (as in: not persisted) values.

Comment: So suggest that use the LocalFolder to save your data.

Comment: Have you some more information on the "abrupt shutdown scenarios" as there may be a different approach?

Comment: @MattLacey It's basically a power off/on. The thing is that a known maximum delay of n secs may be acceptable, the unknown bit is the problem here...

Comment: @mayu In general, once you assign a value to localsetting, it will be saved immediately. Could you please share a simple code sample and detailed steps with me? Then I can follow these steps to reproduce this issue.